# Elasticsearch query not working on fields with capital letters

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have been using/mapping the string field to being index: "not_analyzed" but still not able to get search results for capital letter strings ?? I searched the whole internet inside out , but there is no simple workaround.

Sample data:

```json
{
    "job_status":"Finished",
    "build_number":"94",
    "build_duration":778,
    "@timestamp":"1455317284293",
    "build_result":"UNSTABLE",
    "slave_node":"tiny-cmsbuild03",
    "job_name":"DMWM-WMCore-RunTests-Oracle"
},
{
    "job_status":"Finished",
    "build_number":"96",
    "build_duration":859,
    "@timestamp":"1455662929042",
    "build_result":"UNSTABLE",
    "slave_node":"tiny-cmsbuild02",
    "job_name":"DMWM-WMCore-RunTests-Oracle"
},
{
    "job_status":"Finished",
    "build_number":"89",
    "build_duration":385,
    "@timestamp":"1454453359226",
    "build_result":"UNSTABLE",
    "slave_node":"tiny-cmsbuild06",
    "job_name":"DMWM-WMCore-RunTests-Oracle"
}
```

kibana3 is making this query:

```json
"query": {
       "filtered": {
         "query": {
           "bool": {
             "should": [
               {
                  "query_string": {
                   "query": "job_name:D*"
                 }
               }
             ]
            }
          },
           "filter": {
             "bool": {
               "must": [
               {
                  "match_all": {}
               }
             ]
            }
           }
    }
  }
```

but get no results.

Comment: Maybe you should add some sample document you have indexed, along with its mapping and the query you're trying, it'll be easier for people to help you out.

Comment: ok , thanks , data added

Comment: What query are you running? `term query` or  `query_string` or any other query??

Comment: According to the question, it looks like a query string query directly in the URI (i.e. using `q=...`).

Comment: i am using kibana3 interface , it works for all others , but not for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you don't get any results is because the [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) has a parameter called `lowercase_expanded_terms` which is true by default.

What it does is to lowercase the query string you're passing to it, so that `job_name:D*` becomes `job_name:d*`, hence why nothing is matching.

However, if you query like this, i.e. by setting `lowercase_expanded_terms` to `false`, it will work:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index/_search?lowercase_expanded_terms=false&q=job_name:D*
```

Comment: hi , thanks , but i am using the kibana3 interface , how can i tell kibana not to do that.

Comment: In the advanced settings, you should be able to change the `query:queryString:options` setting and add `"lowercase_expanded_terms": false`

Comment: I think it is not present in kibana3 , is there some way to set it through query

Comment: You can "fix" this by upgrading to Kibana 4... or modifying the Kibana 3 source code. There was a pull request which fixed exactly that, but it was never merged. You simply need to modify two different files and you're good: https://github.com/lookastar/kibana/commit/54a2bbd171dfc7d0de813db4a5d658938fa64637